# Removing duplicates based on composite key in MS access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, flatfilesource

I have imported a flat file .csv file in MS access 2010. It contains following rows:

```
Site_number, Site_name,Tsite_number, Contact_type,First_name, House_name
```

The composite Primary key being **Tsite_number**+**Contact_type**. I need to remove the rows in the table for any duplicate combination of the aforesaid primary key. Please let me know if there are any ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this, from official documentation?

[Find duplicate records with a query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-duplicate-records-with-a-query-3cc805a2-2a13-4439-b0d3-6b23c7d60fbb)

and

[Delete duplicate records with a query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/delete-duplicate-records-with-a-query-4e6c3183-689c-439d-9062-326c85d80a83)

**Find duplicate records:**

To find duplicate records using the Query Wizard, follow these steps.

1) On the Create tab, in the Queries group, click Query Wizard. Note, if you're using Access 2007, on the Create tab, in the Other group, click Query Wizard.

2) In the New Query dialog, click Find Duplicates Query Wizard > OK.

3) In the list of tables, select the table you want to use and click Next.

4) Select the fields that you want to match and click Next.

5) In the list of available fields, select the field or fields that contain the data that you want to update and click Next.

6) Accept the suggested query name or enter a name, and click Finish to run the query.

Comment: Hi , i was looking through this. But the issue is its not considering the composite key

Comment: if you can't find the way to do it - try add another column, that will contains the composite key as one value